# What is the difference between StudlyCaps and camelCase?

Tags: psr-2, psr-1

PSR suggests, method names MUST be declared in camelCase and class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps.

Comment: StudlyCaps ( MyClass, ClientServiceClass, MyInterface... )   camelCase (myVar, i, iCount, ...)

Answer (score 70):

StudlyCaps, also known as PascalCase, implies that the first capital of each subword is capitalized. camelCase implies, like a camel, that the humps are in the middle, therefore the first letter is *not* capitalized.

[Compare Microsoft's standards for .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).

Other well known capitalization styles are snake_case, where all words are concatenated in lowercase with underscores, and kebab-case, which is identical but uses a hyphen.

Comment: It's worth noting that outside of PSR, studly caps refers to  ArbItrAry cApItAlIzAtIOn. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studly_caps

Comment: In fact, StudlyCaps seems to be same as CamelCase. The CamelCase you explained is the "lowerCamelCase", which put the first letter in lowercase.

Answer (score 27):

[CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) is where the first letter of each sub-word in a name is capitalised. The first letter of the whole name can be upper or lower case, and is generally (always?) lower case in programming.

[StudlyCaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studly_caps) is a little weird. There are capital letters, but they can be at any letter according to some rule, not just the beginning of a sub-word. The classic example is (was) HoTMaiL.

My understanding of the PSRs is that their intention is that each sub-word should be capitalised in both instances, with classes having an initial upper-case letter and methods an initial lower-case letter.

Answer (score 12):

In PSR-12 there is an explanation of what they meant by StudlyCaps:

> The term ‘StudlyCaps’ in PSR-1 MUST be interpreted as PascalCase where the first letter of each word is capitalized including the very first letter.

source: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#21-basic-coding-standard

TL;DR

For clarity, there are two versions of camel case:

- UpperCamelCase (initial uppercase letter, also known as **PascalCase**)
- lowerCamelCase (initial lowercase letter, also known as dromedaryCase).

Some people and organizations, notably Microsoft (**and seems the authors of PSR-1 too**), use the term **camel case only for lowerCamelCase**.

PascalCase (or **StudlyCaps**) means exactly UpperCamelCase.

Answer (score 2):

i call it actually PascalCase  when the identifier has two words each one begins with capital letters.. and i use it in C#  for methods names, and camelCase for variablesNames, instanceFelds.. ClassNames also for PasaclCase..

Answer (score 1):

### camelCase:

`$camelCase`
`$myVar`

*Only* first letter of sub-words, not first letter of the property itself should be uppercase

### StudlyCaps:

`$StudlyCaps`
`$MyVar`

property starts with uppercase also first letter of sub-words

maybe find it useful:
[psr property naming recommendation](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#42-properties)

[psr](/questions/tagged/psr)[psr-1](/questions/tagged/psr-1)[studlycaps](/questions/tagged/studlycaps)[studly-caps](/questions/tagged/studly-caps)[camelcase](/questions/tagged/camelcase)